# How to package an Apache module with Maven

Tags: maven-2, apache2, packaging

1. I have a apache_mod.c which is supposed to be updated for continuous integration
2. I would like to use Maven to compile this module for generating apache_mod.so
3. Then packaging it in .jar

I can't find how to compile the apache_mod.c with Maven to get apache_mod.so because it seems that an Apache2 module needs to be compiled with apxs2 command which already put the *.so file in /usr/lib/apache2/modules.

So, do you have any idea how to compile apache_mod.c with Maven in order to get apache_mod.so to package it?

Comment: Why do you need to put so file to a jar archive? This sounds like completely wrong way of doing things. Can you elaborate a bit more about reasons, and maybe we can find better way to solve your problem. Btw, apxs2 is just wrapper around gcc, so the way to compile c or c++ files under mave would be with the native plugin  http://mojo.codehaus.org/maven-native/native-maven-plugin/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that putting *.so (shared object) into jar archive is correct solution, but to answer your question how to compile native c or c++ files using maven, you can use the native plugin http://mojo.codehaus.org/maven-native/native-maven-plugin/. Also, the apxs2 is just wrapper around gcc, so you don't have to use apxs2 to build apache module. You can just use gcc.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. My goal is to build an assembly containing *.so in order to deliver it. I'll have a try to directly compile *.c with gcc adding needed libraries then use the native plugin to make it automatically in a maven assembly process.

Comment: Definitly right. Compiling with native plugin then packaging with assembly plugin works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Seems I tried to do two things in one.
Generating *.so and packaging it are two different things.
So here is the process :

1. Having a Maven project compiling and generating *.so
2. Having a Maven Assembly to package *.so and others files and *.war

Comment: Comments are welcome to tell if I'm wrong or not then i can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Seems Boris has been definitly right. Using Maven native plugin allow to compile *.c in *.so then Maven assembly plugin is used to package it.

Thanks for all.